# Redirecting to SSL and non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, safari, plesk

I'm trying to redirect:

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
```

.. to ..

```
https://example.com
```

I'm doing this because I have certs for https://example.com but not https://www.example.com

All works fine except the `https://www.example.com` which, in Safari, gives 'This connection is not private' error. In Chrome it's fine.

```
# BEGIN redirect www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# END redirect


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

There are some Plesk settings which might effect this too (see image), but I have't got it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `Preferred domain: example.com` and `Permanent SEO-safe 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS` will allow you to achieve the required results.

I would suggest removing the same redirects from `.htaccess`, since once it is defined in Apache configuration, duplicating rewrites may lead to conflicts resulting, for example, in `Too many redirects` errors.

If it still won't work in Safari, check [Safari Develop menu](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/use-the-safari-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac) for additional symptoms and google it or include it into the question.